# Hard Determinism and the Java Random generator

Tags: java, random

My roommate and I are in another argument about our free will. His newest argument against my sweet sweet deterministic world view is that random number generators like the one in Java is unpredictable and nothing prior to running a random generator can determine the outcome of the number.

Anyway, my question is that when you use the built in Java random methods like Math.random and java.util.Random, is the number truly random or is it dependent on any predictable event? Totally need this for my code.

Comment: No, it's not specified to be truly random. There's a reason they're called **pseudo**random number generators.

Comment: There is only "true" randomness in nature, and that is quantum physics. Until we'll understand why it seems random ...

Comment: Random.org has some good information about true randomness and offers a solution to your problems.

Comment: Most of the source code for Java's runtime classes is available online at grepcode.com. The code for `java.util.Random` is fairly readable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the output of the `Random` class does depend on predictable events. The class uses an algorithm to produce the pseudorandom numbers. As the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) say:

> The general contract of next is that it returns an int value and if the argument bits is between 1 and 32 (inclusive), then that many low-order bits of the returned value will be (approximately) independently chosen bit values, each of which is (approximately) equally likely to be 0 or 1. The method next is implemented by class Random by atomically updating the seed to
>
> ```
> (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)
> ```
>
> and returning
>
> ```
> (int)(seed >>> (48 - bits)).
> ```
>
> This is a linear congruential pseudorandom number generator, as defined by D. H. Lehmer and described by Donald E. Knuth in The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 3: Seminumerical Algorithms, section 3.2.1.